# What is SOCKET accept() error errno 316?

Tags: c, linux, macos, sockets

On OSX I keep getting a socket error of 316 after calling accept() on a bound & listening socket.
I get a valid socket returned, and I believe I then use it fine, (though I may not be, I need to double check this, as I am accepting hundreds of connections at any moment) but errno has been set.

I'm trying to understand [the documentation on the unix accept(2) man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) which notes (which, incidentally, is missing from [apple's accept() documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/accept.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/accept))

> Linux accept() (and accept4()) passes already-pending network errors
>   on the new socket as an error code from accept(). This behavior
>   differs from other BSD socket implementations. For reliable operation
>   the application should detect the network errors defined for the
>   protocol after accept() and treat them like EAGAIN by retrying.

now, 316 works out as 256 OR'd with ETIMEDOUT(60). So, I'm curious as to how I should be handling this;

1. If ANY error is set after accept(), should I accept() again?
2. Should I close() the SOCKET that accept DID return?
3. Are the unix
   errno code's 8 bit? (all the codes I see are <128) and is this an
   erroneous bit set in memory, or is it a special flag, like a warning
   (I cannot find any documentation on the errno format's)
4. Does this error mean the connection I just popped from the stack timed out... itself and the OS disconnected them, or wasn't accept()'d by me fast enough?

Comment: How would this "*... keep getting a socket error of 316 after calling accept() on a bound & listening socket. I get a valid socket returned,*" work? You only want to check `errno` if `accept()` returned `-1`, which in turn is not a valid socket descriptor.

Comment: This is what I originally thought, but the quoted docs say "passes already-pending network errors on the new socket". New socket here means... my existing socket? or the new socket it generates?

Comment: Though, I have just popped all errors before calling `accept()` and I have a feeling it's just an old error code afterall, so I'm not checking for errors after some other call...

Comment: Hmhmja, the Linux man-page also continues listing the code to check against for TCP/IP. So what I'd do (for Linux) was to set  `errno` to `0` before calling `accpet()` and then after `accept()` returned a value `>=0` to only test `errno` against `ENETDOWN`, `EPROTO`, `ENOPROTOOPT`, `EHOSTDOWN`, `ENONET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`, `EOPNOTSUPP` and `ENETUNREACH`, as listed. Please note that this behaviour is documented for Linux **only**. No need to to this on OSX.

Comment: OS X networking is based on BSD, so does not exhibit Linux weirdness.  On OSX `ELAST` is the largest errno, 106 on 10.9.  As @alk said, **do not** examine `errno` unless `accept()` has returned -1.

Comment: ELAST is a good bit of information, is there some documentation that I should not get an error over this? the error of 316 still persists, but maybe that's for a seperate SO question

Comment: The *intro(2)* manual page should always list all valid `errno` values, and their generic meaning, and in theory all other library and system call manual pages should list the values that can be expected _when the call returns an error indication_ and more specific meanings for those cases.  (Apple is worse than some vendors at keeping manual pages up to date though.)

Comment: BTW, In my reading of the Linux documentation, the `errno` value is still only of concern if `accept()` has returned `-1`.  What they mean is that if you get an error from `accept()` (i.e. it returns -1), _and_ if `errno` immediately after the return is not one documented for `accept()` then _and only then_ translate it to `EAGAIN` and act appropriately.  Even on Linux a valid descriptor means **ignore errno**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not examine `errno` unless `accept()` has returned -1.  If `accept()` returns a valid file descriptor then the value of `errno` is **undefined**.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer. The real resolution was that this error was being triggered by my *successful*  `socket()` creation (and I get it in UDP and TCP) and in fact I was examining that error, not for accept. As for the wierd errono itself, that's maybe for a seperate question

Comment: meta: should I "resolve" this question in someway like "not a real problem"?

Comment: I don't know how to say it more explicitly:  **Do not ever** examine `errno` _unless_ the very most recent function returned an indication of an actual error occurring!  It has no meaning, and its value is undefined in any and all cases where the most recent function succeeded.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, didn't apply that logic to `socket()` :) Assuming 316 is just some erroneous value then, thanks